# Text Binder in Web Api Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I have a simple text binder to modify strings in my web api project. This binder should change all strings in all models.

```
public class TextoBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (result == null)
            return false;

        var value = result.AttemptedValue.Trim();

        // value changes here

        bindingContext.Model = value;

        return true;
    }
}
```

This TextoBinder class is registered as a Service:

```
config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(string), new TextoBinder()));
```

The problem is that the Web Api doesn't call this binder when binding an input model as the MVC does in a similar application. I know the way the incomming data is treated is not the same in MVC and Web Api, but I could not make the text binder works for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

With a model-binding provider, you still need to add the [TextoBinder] attribute to the parameter, to tell Web API that it should use a model binder and not a media-type formatter.

You can take help of [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Thank you @Guanxi, I will read more about that as this topic looks important.

Comment: I have added link to document that has been quite helpful to me in understanding this.